# Check if resource belongs to user before deleting/updating it

Tags: java, spring

Here's my spring endpoint:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Package> deletePackage(JwtAuthenticationToken principal,
                                             @PathVariable Long id) {
    Package parcel = packageService.retrievePackage(id);
    checkResourceBelongsToUser(principal, parcel);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(packageService.deletePackage(parcel), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

And here's my current way of checking if the current resource the user is trying to update/delete belongs to the user:

```
private void checkResourceBelongsToUser(Address address, AppUser user) {
    if (!address.getUser().getId().equals(user.getId())) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "Not allowed to access/modify resource");
    }
}
```

This method will check if the Address belongs to the user.

- The address was gotten from a id in the path variable
- The user was gotten from the id in the JWT

Update and delete endpoint call the `checkResourceBelongsToUser` method before doing any processing (updating or deleting). I'm comparing ids. Is my method enough to check if the user truly has access?

Comment: This depends on the JWT and how you handle it - for example is it created by a backend that you trust or the client (usually untrusted)? Is it encrypted or signed? You need to verify the JWT in order to use it for this kind of operation.
More information can be found here: https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/vulnerabilities